# How to obtain the conversaton info of previous participants when you have installed the teams app?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

I have a teams bot. When I installed it for the first time, I can obtain the conversation info of new participants through the bot services. But when I have installed the teams app, How can I get the conversation info of previous participants?

find the botframework sdk about how to obtain the conversation info of previous participants

Comment: There is no way to get the conversation info of previous participants when installing teams app.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't get this by yourself again, as the "installationUpdate" event only occurs once, but it actually does send the same information you need every time the user messages your bot, so if your bot accepts messages just extract the information then.